# Defining multiple self-relations on the same model with prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I could use some help with self relations.

So we basically have a microservice that handles callbacks/postbacks from other another company. A callback can either be completely new, with no relations, or it can be a callback that updates another previous callback, so it has a relation with that callback.

I won't got into too much details, but if it's a callback that is related to another callback, they provide the reference id of the other callback. And that's how we come up with the relation.

This worked perfect with the self relations that is detailed here:
https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/self-relations

```
referenceId String?   @unique  

reference  Callback?  @relation("CallbackHistory", fields: [referenceId], references: [id])  

referenceOf Callback? @relation("CallbackHistory")
```

Now here's the problem we encountered - we'd like to have a way to know what the original callback is in this chain of callbacks.  Ideally, we'd like to pass along that relation to all the callbacks that related to eachother.  We realized self relations can only have two sides however - so we can't simply add a:

```
original Callback? @relation("CallbackHistory")
```

And we're struggling coming up with another relation name if we'd define another self-relation, nevertheless what we would call the other side of this "original" relation.

Does anyone have here have any input on this? Would appreciate it a ton.

Thanks!